# Compute the sample variance $s_6^2=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^6(x_i-\overline{x}_6)^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $x_1,...,x_6$ be a realization of a random sample $X_1,...,X_6$ from a $Ber(p)$ distribution. It is given that the realized sample mean $\overline{x} _6 = 0.3$. Compute the sample variance $s_6^2=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^6(x_i-\overline{x}_6)^2$.

How can I compute the sample variance? I really don't know how to start this exercise? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Expand the sum. What can you say about $x_i^2$ and hence $\sum x_i^2$ when $x_i$'s are Bernoulli?

Comment: Since the sample is from a Bernoulli distribution $x_i = x_2$ for all $i$.

Comment: Relate $x_i^2$ with $x_i$, and hence $\sum x_i^2$ with $\overline{x}_6$.

Comment: The question is a little odd: the sample mean should be one of $\frac06,\frac16,\frac26,\frac36,\frac46,\frac56,\frac66$ while $0.3$ is none of those

Comment: You are right, but it's what is given